# Select rows which meets criteria and do not

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table FEATURE and FEATURE_DETAILS
FEATURE_DETAILS can have a lot of FEATUREs.

```
  FEATURE_DETAILS
  feature_deatails_id | feature_id
  1                        1
  1                        2
  1                        4 
  2                        1
  2                        2
  2                        4
  2                        5
```

I have a blocker in selecting feature_deatails_id's which have e.g. 5 feature_id OR null where absent.
So the output should be:

```
feature_deatails_id | feature_id
1                     null
2                     5
```

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention - plsql

Comment: PL/SQL is the language used in Oracle to write stored procedures. It's not the name of a DBMS

Answer (score 0):

For example, you could just return the column's value, if it meets your criteria.

```
select
feature_details_id
, max(case when feature_id = 5 then feature_id else null) as feature_id
from table
group by feature_details_id
```

Or you could do it like following. Select every possible feature_detail_id, then left join the results:

```
select * from 
(
select distinct
feature_details_id
from table
) a left join (
select feature_details_id, feature_id 
from table
where feature_id = 5
group by feature_details_id
) b using (feature_details_id);
```

Note: First approach is much better performance-wise. Second approach is more for understanding and learning.

- see them both working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b377e/5/0)

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
select feature_deatails_id, min(case feature_id when 5 then feature_id end) feature_id
from my_table
group by feature_details_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also join table on itself, using it like this

```
select distinct f1.feature_deatails_id, f2.feature_id 
       from FEATURE_DETAILS f1
LEFT JOIN FEATURE_DETAILS f2 on f1.feature_deatails_id = f2.feature_deatails_id 
                             and f2.feature_id = 5
```